# Formula for the number of the last 1 in the binary vector

Tags: combinatorics

Given a binary vector $x=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$; $x_k \in \{0,1\}$ $\forall k\in\overline{1,n}$.

It is obvious that the number of $1$'s in the vector $x$ is equal to the sum of all its coordinates: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k$.

Does there exist an analogous 'analytical formula' for the number $\nu$ of the last $1$ in the vector $x$, that is, $\nu=\max\{k\in\overline{1,n}: x_k=1\}$.

(If $x=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ then, by definition, $\nu=0$.)

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the formula recursively. Say that $\nu(n-1)$ is the number $\nu$ of the last 1 in the vector of length $n-1$. Then $\nu(n)$ can be written as $\nu(n-1) - \nu(n-1) \cdot x_n + n \cdot x_n$ (and $\nu(1) = x_1$). For instance, $\nu(3) = x_1 - x_1 x_2 + 2 x_2 - x_1 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 - 2 x_2 x_3 + 3x_3$.